# Массив с разными типами данных

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, указатели, наследование

Есть основной класс Human, есть наследуемый от него Doctor. Нужно сделать массив, в котором будут как объекты первого класса, так и второго. Я своим скудным умишкой додумался только до этого.

```
#include "Human.h"
#include "Doctor.h"

using namespace std;

void main() {

int n = 0;
cout << "How many? ";
cin >> n;
int m;
Human **uni;
ofstream fout("humans.txt", ios::app);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "1 for Human\n2 for Doctor ";
    cin >> m;
    switch (m) {
    case 1: {
                uni[i] = new Human(); \\в этой строке возникает ошибка
                uni[i]->Set(cin);
                uni[i]->InFile(fout);
                break;
    }
    case 2: {
                uni[i] = new Doctor();
                uni[i]->Set(cin);
                uni[i]->InFile(fout);
                break;
    }
        default: cout << "Wrong input."; system("pause");
              }
    }
}
```

Но вылазит ошибка:

> Error 1   error C4700: uninitialized local variable

Подскажите, что нужно исправить, чтобы заработало. Или может это можно сделать как-то по-другому?

Comment: Это ошибка компиляции, правильно? Тогда вас не должно затруднить подсказать нам, в какой строке она возникает.

Comment: В строке: uni[i] = new Human();

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Переменная `uni` объявлена, но не инициализирована

```
Human **uni;
```

Поэтому использования случайного значения этой переменной в предложениях

```
uni[i] = new Human();
```

и

```
uni[i] = new Doctor();
```

ведет к неопределенному поведению программы, о чем компилятор вам любезно сообщил.

Вам сначала надо выделить память под массив указателей на базовый класс

```
uni = new Human *[n];
```

и только затем вы можете инициализировать элементы этого массива в предложениях

```
uni[i] = new Human();
```

и

```
uni[i] = new Doctor();
```

Также вы должны не забыть освободить всю выделенную память в обратном порядке, когда массив объектов больше вам будет не нужен.

В подобных случаях лучше использовать стандартный класс `std::vector`. Например,

```
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<Human *> uni;
```

И еще лучше использовать умные указатели

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>    

//...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Human>> uni;
```

В этом случае вам не надо беспокоиться об освобождении памяти и вызовах деструкторов объектов.

Имейте в виду, что в C++ функция main без параметров должна быть объявлена как

```
int main()
```

то есть она должна иметь тип возвращаемого значения `int`.

Кроме того ваша программа содержит баг, так как в случае, когда пользователь в цикле введет неверное значение, то есть ни 1 и ни 2, то элемент массива останется не инициализированным и пропущенным.

По крайней мере вам следует ввод значения также заключить в цикл. Например,

```
do
{
    cout << "1 for Human\n2 for Doctor ";
    cin >> m;
} while ( m != 1 && m != 2 );
```

И только после этого цикла размещать `switch` предложение. Также вместо магических чисел 1 и 2 лучше объявить перечисление. Например

```
enum { HUMAN = 1, DOCTOR = 2 };
```

и использовать эти константы в `switch` предложении

```
switch (m) {
case HUMAN: {
            uni[i] = new Human(); \\в этой строке возникает ошибка
            uni[i]->Set(cin);
            uni[i]->InFile(fout);
            break;
}
case DOCTOR: {
            uni[i] = new Doctor();
            uni[i]->Set(cin);
            uni[i]->InFile(fout);
            break;
}
//...
```

Надеюсь, что деструктор базового класса объявлен со спецификатором функции `virtual`, не так ли?:)

Answer (score 2):

Надо для массива память выделить.

```
Human **uni = new Human*[n];
```

Comment: @O.Y.: Хм, странно. А если откомпилировать, какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: @VladD Ой, это я ошибся, всё заработало. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @VladD вы вопрос автора перечитайте, пожалуйста. Особенно в части "Подскажите, что нужно исправить, чтобы заработало")

Comment: @O.Y.: Спасибо уходит автору правильного ответа :)

Comment: @Umed: Это был вопрос к (удалённому) комментарию ТС к вашему ответу.

Comment: @VladD, не будем ругаться. Доброй ночи и желаю Вам удачи:)